# I'm getting a NoReverseMatch error but I think my files are valid

Tags: python, django, django-views

From my base.html:

```
<div id="button_container">
            <button class="button"><a href="{% url 'home' %}"> HOME </a></button>
            <button class="button"><a href="{% url 'rooms' %}"> ROOMS & SUITES </button>
            <button class="button"><a href="{% url 'roomBookingsList' %}"> ROOM BOOKINGS </button>
    </div>
```

Urls.py:

```
path('rooms/mybooking', views.roomBookingsList, name='roomBookingsList'),
```

Views.py:

```
def roomBookingsList(request):
        suiteBookingList = Suite_booking.objects.all()
        context = {
            'suiteBookingList': suiteBookingList,
        }
        return render (request, 'roomBookingsList.html', context=context)
```

roomBookingsList.html:

```
{% for suiteBookingList in suiteBookingList %}
        <li> {{ suiteBookingList }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

So when I run it and click the ROOM BOOKINGS from the base.html, it will show me whatever rooms I have booked. No problem here. I also want to add an edit button here so I can update the booking if I accidentally typo the name or something.

So I added in the roomBookingsList.html:

```
{% for suiteBookingList in suiteBookingList %}
        <li> {{ suiteBookingList }}</li> - <a href="{% url 'edit_suite' suite.id %}">Edit</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Added in urls.py:

```
path('rooms/suite/edit/<int:suite_id>', views.edit_suite, name='edit_suite'),
```

Added in views.py:

```
def edit_suite(request, suite_id):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            suite = Suite_booking.objects.get(pk=suite_id)
            form = BookingForm(request.POST, instance=suite)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('roomBookingsList'))
        else:
            suite = Suite_booking.objects.get(pk=suite_id)
            fields = model_to_dict(suite)
            form = BookingForm(initial=fields, instance=suite)
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'type': 'edit',
        }
        return render(request, 'roomBookingsList.html', context=context)
```

Then I tried to run it again, and this time when I click the ROOM BOOKINGS button, it gave an error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /system/rooms/mybooking
    Reverse for 'edit_suite' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['system/rooms/suite/edit/(?P<suite_id>[0-9]+)$']
```

In the traceback there's this:

```
D:\ssip\hotel\system\views.py, line 59, in roomBookingsList 
    59. return render (request, 'roomBookingsList.html', context=context)
```

I tried searching all the files I used for the `('',)` but didn't find any. I also looked over my `def roomBookingsList` but didn't find anything odd in it. I already tried searching the error but most answers were OP forgetting the dot or underscore when passing args.

Is it because I'm calling `Suite_booking` object in both the `def roomBookingsList` and `edit_suite`? What should I change here?

Sorry it's long and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `suite.id` does not exist. Shouldn't it be `suiteBookingList.id` instead?

```
{% for suiteBookingList in suiteBookingList %}
        <li> {{ suiteBookingList }}</li> - <a href="{% url 'edit_suite' suiteBookingList.id %}">Edit</a>
{% endfor %}
```

And though it works, I would recommend not using the same name as your variable to iterate:

```
{% for suite in suiteBookingList %}
        <li> {{ suite }}</li> - <a href="{% url 'edit_suite' suite.id %}">Edit</a>
{% endfor %}
```